# Error in webservice after publishing

Tags: c#, web-services

I created a webservice when it hosted on my local computer it works fine, but when i publish it to the web host, it doesnt work any more, i guess its a question about how the webserver is configured, but can i make some changes in web.config so it will work?

### The error i get is below:

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=5.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

Line 37:                
Line 38:                
Line 39:                
Line 40:        
Line 41:

Source File: c:\webs\talkactive\gb1634\qaz.dk\web.config    Line: 39

### Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=5.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.

The webservice uses a c# class placed in the app_code folder. That c# class uses mysql. 
When i use the class in a normal .aspx file it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the obvious thing would be to check whether the MySql.Data exist in the GAC (or the web service's bin folder) on the server and is of the correct version and public key?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are missing this DLL. You should look at putting it in the bin directory of your webservice.

Answer (score 0):

There could also be a versioning conflict between the MySql client you want and what is installed on the server. You can add the following section to your web.config file and specify the proper version/public key you need:

```
<compilation debug="false">
   <assemblies>       
      <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=5.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```